# Lpf ramp response intution

Tags: capacitor, low-pass, remote-control

[image]How to intutively draw ramp response of low pass filter intutively . I am able to do it from laplace transform but i am unable to understand..

Comment: Why don't you provide a specific example circuit that you can't intuitively understand?

Comment: The integral of a ramp (e.g. \$t\$), is a parabola (e.g. \$t^2/2\$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage change on the capacitor is proportional to the current through the resistor.  This, in turn, is proportional to the voltage across the resistor.  The end result, intuitively, is that the output will change at a rate proportional to the difference between the input and the output.

Given a ramp input, the output will change slowly at first, but will increase as the input voltage outpaces it.  When the input voltage reaches maximum, the output will increase more and more slowly as it catches up.  All in all, you will see a sort of S-shaped response, which you should recognize from the Laplace solution.

Comment: @Rac Just a minor addition: if you subtract the output from the input you'll get the step response, 1-exp(-t/RC).